# Calculating the percentage across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I own a car racing company with a database that has information of all the races and racers. The database has a table for all of the racers (RacerID, first name, last name, contactInfo etc.) , and another table for all of the races (RaceID, racer1, racer1, winningRacerID, winningTime).

How would you calculate the winning percentage of each racer?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will give you winning percentage by each racer

Query, SQL fiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12aa3/1)

```
 select RacerID, FirstName, LastName, count(Races.WinningRacerID) * 100.0 / (select count(1) from Races) as WinningPercentage
 from
    Racers
    left join Races on Racers.RacerID = Races.WinningRacerID
 group by
    RacerID, FirstName, LastName
```

Note: Assumption there is alteast 1 record in Race table if not need to check for divide by 0 error.